# Как исправить ошибку при импорте socket io в Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, socket.io

Я хочу использовать **socket.io** в своем расширении, но когда я импортирую библиотеку, расширение выкидывает ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Я выяснил, что **socket.io** делает проверку `document` и `window`,
 но в `background.js` я не могу использовать ни `document API`, ни `window object`.

Я использую **manifest v3**.

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы использовать **socket.io**?

Comment: Никто вам не мешает создать `document` или `window` в `background.js` или форкнуть исходную библиотеку и убрать проверку.

Comment: А если без костылей?

Comment: Просто тогда мое расширение полностью завязано на мокапы, которые буду пилить для каждой проверки DOM, с другой стороны, если менять код, то придется делать это в каждых последующих версиях

Comment: "А если без костылей?" сделать форк и пулл реквест в репозиторий с добавленным функционалом для расширений.